# Python3: Is there a way to make it so my function prints pi with only two decimals if the user chooses to input no argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, parameter-passing

Is there a way to make it so my function prints pi with only two decimal places if the user chooses to input no argument? The below function takes one argument (namely 'n') which in turn returns an error if the user chooses to leave the field blank:

```
def pi(n):

    pi_input = round(math.pi, n)

    # None is unfruitful here, I just wanna emphasize my desired objective
    if n <= 1 or n == None:
        return pi(2)

    elif n > 15:
        print("Too many decimal places.")
        return math.pi

    else:
        return pi_input
```

The desired outcome should be as follows:

```
>>> pi()
3.14
```

I was wondering if there was a way to somehow short-circuit the function so the function does not necessarily require an input. If not, I wouldn't mind a more intelligent rewriting of the code. I greatly appreciate all help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a [default argument](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values) to your function so that the `n` variable is set to 2 if nothing is provided.

```py
def pi(n: int = 2):

    pi_input = round(math.pi, n)

    if n > 15:
        print("Too many decimal places.")
        return math.pi
    else:
        return pi_input
```

Or simply:

```py
def pi(n: int = 2):
    return round(math.pi, n)
```

Which would produce:

```
>> result = pi()
>> print(result)
3.14
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick solution! It did the job.